# How to find the "voltage across each winding" for different delta and star connections in a three phase transformer system?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, y-to-delta

I have got results from testing with delta/delta, delta/star, star/delta and star/star configurations. I've got the line and phase voltages for each configuration for both primary and secondary coils.
I need to calculate the voltage across each winding and find the turns ratio. I'm just a bit confused about the winding voltage. Do I just use the line voltage? Is there a formula that I have been unable to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star

line to line voltage =  √3 x Winding voltage

line current = winding current.

Delta

line to line voltage = winding voltage

line current =  √3  x winding current.

The root 3 comes from the vector subtraction of two phases separated by 120 degrees.